# CDN Link when using AppEngine Page Speed

Tags: google-app-engine, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using PageSpeed for my app; I see that my css files are being combined into one but it uses google static content https://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/sx/s....

I need to have this final file loaded from my cdn (Cloudfront with active mapping to the same origin). It works on normal pagespeed installations on nginx.

How do I rewrite domains for pagespeed optimized file which is being loaded from google static server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be confusing because there are several distinct PageSpeed optimization products:

- **mod_pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed** are modules you install on your server, they allow you to rewrite resources onto any other domain (including your CDN).
- **PageSpeed Service** is a service run by Google. You change your DNS to point to Google's servers and Google's serve the HTML and all the resources. When using PageSpeed Service, all resources get rewritten to the `googleusercontent.com` domain. I don't believe there is any option to change that to point to your CDN instead.

If you signed up for PageSpeed through App Engine, you are using **PageSpeed Service** and AFAIK there is no way to rewrite resources to a separate CDN.

Note that `googleusercontent.com` has many of the advantages of a CDN, it provides caching and low latency serving across the globe.